# Is there a simple closed curve in the plane whose length is six meters and bounds an area of three square meters?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have tried it for a rectangle if I could find sides of rectangle whose length is six meters and area is three square meters. Let $x$ and $y$ be the length and breadth of rectangle. The product of $x$ and $y$ is three square meters which is area and perimeter is twice the sum of length and breadth is six meters. On calculating, I got the complex values of $x$ and $y$. whether I have tried according to the statement of question else if I am wrong in solving the problem. Then please guide which will be the correct simple closed curve for this condition.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `general-topology`, or with `measure-theory`?

Comment: Isn't the optimal shape for maximizing area with given perimeter a circle? Because a circle with perimeter (circumference) 6 has area less than 3, so it's impossible?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461853/given-a-fixed-perimeter-which-shape-will-have-the-maximum-area

Comment: The maximum area you can have with a given perimeter $p$ is $\frac{p^2}{4 \pi }$

Comment: Thanku so much Raffaele

Answer (score 4):

To bound an area of $3$ square metres the least possible curve length is such that the curve is a circle, by the [isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality). This circle will have a radius of $\sqrt{\frac3\pi}$ metres and a length of $2\pi\sqrt{\frac3\pi}=6.1399\dots$ metres. Since we only have $6$ metres to work with, the task is impossible.

For the same reason, we cannot enclose $4$ square metres with a $7$-metre curve, nor $8$ with $10$, but we can enclose $5$ with $8$.